# How to capture keystrokes with a Python daemon?

Tags: python, linux, keyboard, capture

I'm trying to write a POS-style application for a [Sheevaplug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SheevaPlug) that does the following:

1. Captures input from a card reader (as I understand, most mag card readers emulate keyboard input, so basically I'm looking to capture that)
2. Doesn't require X
3. Runs in the background (daemon)

I've seen examples of code that will wait for STDIN, but that won't work because this is a background process with no login, not even a monitor actually.

I also found this snippet [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859049/check-if-key-is-pressed-using-python-a-daemon-in-the-background) on this site:

```
from struct import unpack
port = open("/dev/input/event1","rb")    

while 1:    
    a,b,c,d = unpack("4B",port.read(4))    
    print a,b,c,d
```

Which, while being the closest thing to what I need so far, only generates a series of numbers, all of which are different with no way that I know of to translate them into useful values.

Clearly, I'm missing something here, but I don't know what it is.  Can someone please how to get the rest of the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 5 of the Linux kernel [input documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) describes what each of the values in the event interface means.

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks so much for your help, this should be enough to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

the format is explained in the [kernel documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/) in section *5. Event Interface*.